# Deploying Flask app with psycopg2 dependency to Elastic Beanstalk. ec2 instance won't install yum packages

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having problems deploying my flask app to EB.

I'm using eb-cli. I've created a **.ebextensions** folder in the root folder of my application. The folder contains two files:

**00dependencies.config**

```
packages:
  yum:
    libffi-devel : []
    postgresql95-devel: []
```

**01setup.config**

```
container_commands:
  00_wsgi_pass_headers:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "api-siifra/manage.py"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "api-siifra/app/static/"
```

But when I run **eb deploy** I get the error:

```
ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

Looking in the eb web interface under **Health** I see the error:

```
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

And the command fails on: **Error: pg_config executable not found.** while installing **psycopg2**

If I ssh in to the ec2 instance in question and install *postgresql95-devel* manually the **eb deploy** command returns with out errors.

I though packages: yum: .... in a *.config file ran before the pip command?

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Thank you.